# Non-blocking multiprocessing.connection.Listener?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, python-3.3, python-multiprocessing

I use multiprocessing.connection.Listener for communication between processes, and it works as a charm for me. Now i would really love my mainloop to do something else between commands from client. Unfortunately listener.accept() blocks execution until connection from client process is established.

Is there a simple way of managing non blocking check for multiprocessing.connection? Timeout? Or shall i use a dedicated thread?

```
    # Simplified code:

    from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

    def mainloop():
        listener = Listener(address=(localhost, 6000), authkey=b'secret')

        while True:
            conn = listener.accept() # <---  This blocks!
            msg = conn.recv() 
            print ('got message: %r' % msg)
            conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution that I found (although it might not be the most "elegant" solution is using `conn.poll`. ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#Connection.poll)) Poll returns `True` if the Listener has new data, and (most importantly) is nonblocking if no argument is passed to it. I'm not 100% sure that this is the best way to do this, but I've had success with only running `listener.accept()` once, and then using the following syntax to repeatedly get input (if there is any available)

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

def mainloop():
    running = True

    listener = Listener(address=(localhost, 6000), authkey=b'secret')
    conn = listener.accept()
    msg = ""

    while running:
        while conn.poll():
            msg = conn.recv() 
            print (f"got message: {msg}")

            if msg == "EXIT":
                running = False

        # Other code can go here
        print(f"I can run too! Last msg received was {msg}")

     conn.close()
```

The 'while' in the conditional statement can be replaced with 'if,' if you only want to get a maximum of one message at a time. Use with caution, as it seems sort of 'hacky,' and I haven't found references to using `conn.poll` for this purpose elsewhere.

Comment: have you tried and tested it? Is it reliable now?

Comment: Yes, it's generally very reliable, though I am by no means an expert on multiprocessing systems. It's been working without issue on a project that I have, so  yes, I'd say that it has been working reliably for me. With that said, this is a quick solution, but there may be a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: Note that this does not address OP's question. OP's problem is that accept() blocks, not recv() blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the blocking function in a thread:

```
conn = await loop.run_in_executor(None, listener.accept)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the Listener object myself- for this task I normally use `multiprocessing.Queue`; doco at the following link:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue

That object can be used to send and receive any pickle-able object between Python processes with a nice API; I think you'll be most interested in:

- in process A

  - `.put('some message')`
- in process B

  - `.get_nowait()  # will raise Queue.Empty if nothing is available- handle that to move on with your execution`

The only limitation with this is you'll need to have control of both Process objects at some point in order to be able to allocate the queue to them- something like this:

```
import time
from Queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


def receiver(q):
    while 1:
        try:
            message = q.get_nowait()
            print 'receiver got', message
        except Empty:
            print 'nothing to receive, sleeping'
            time.sleep(1)


def sender(q):
    while 1:
        message = 'some message'
        q.put('some message')
        print 'sender sent', message
        time.sleep(1)


some_queue = Queue()

process_a = Process(
    target=receiver,
    args=(some_queue,)
)

process_b = Process(
    target=sender,
    args=(some_queue,)
)

process_a.start()
process_b.start()

print 'ctrl + c to exit'
try:
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

process_a.terminate()
process_b.terminate()

process_a.join()
process_b.join()
```

Queues are nice because you can actually have as many consumers and as many producers for that exact same Queue object as you like (handy for distributing tasks).

I should point out that just calling `.terminate()` on a Process is bad form- you should use your shiny new messaging system to pass a shutdown message or something of that nature.

Comment: To elaborate on the "you'll need to have control of both Process objects", if this is to permit two processes that are started at different times or perhaps exist on different servers altogether then I'm afraid my advice is useless- I imagine you'd need a thread or something, for that purpose I normally use gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing module comes with a nice feature called Pipe(). It is a nice way to share resources between two processes(never tried more than two before). With the dawn of python 3.80 came the shared memory function in the multiprocessing module but i have not really tested that so i cannot vouch for it
You will use the pipe function something like

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe

.....

def sending(conn):
    message = 'some message'
    #perform some code
    conn.send(message)
    conn.close()

receiver, sender = Pipe()
p = Process(target=sending, args=(sender,))
p.start()
print receiver.recv()   # prints "some message"
p.join()
```

with this you should be able to have separate processes running independently and when you get to the point which you need the input from one process. If there is somehow an error due to the unrelieved data of the other process you can put it on a kind of sleep or halt or use a while loop to constantly check pending when the other process finishes with that task and sends it over

```
while not parent_conn.recv():
    time.sleep(5)
```

this should keep it in an infinite loop until the other process is done running and sends the result. This is also about 2-3 times faster than Queue. Although queue is also a good option personally I do not use it.